# How to install gphoto2?

Tags: python-2.7, libgphoto2

Whenever I try to install gphoto2 using pip this error message pops up:

---

C:\Python27>pip install gphoto2

```
Collecting gphoto2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/20/16f4e17e0d799199c84
a7d3e4f181232071383acf71912da44de015b1812/gphoto2-1.8.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: command "pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2" failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MACIE_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xybqgvtu\gphoto2\se
tup.py", line 38, in <module>
    cmd, stderr=FNULL, universal_newlines=True).split('.')
  File "c:\users\macie_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subpro
cess.py", line 376, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\users\macie_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subpro
cess.py", line 453, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "c:\users\macie_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subpro
cess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\users\macie_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subpro
cess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MACIE_~1
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xybqgvtu\gphoto2\
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the standalone version from sourceforge.
1) download libusb & gphoto
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/libusb-win32-releases/

https://code.google.com/p/scan-manager/downloads/detail?name=gphoto-2.4.14-win32-build2.zip&can=2&q=

2) unzip both files

3) connect your camera and switch it on

4) install libusb
run `inf-wizard` from libusb/bin folder, select your camera and click install

5) run `gphoto2` from gphoto2/bin folder